# How to print a table of two with incremental skipping

Tags: python

I want to print a series of numbers with incremental skipping of numbers like:   `(1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Output:

```
2,6,12,20,30,42,.....
```

Comment: Briefly explain your problem. what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import accumulate
assert list(accumulate(range(2, 14, 2))) == [2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42]
assert list(accumulate(range(30, -30, -6))) == [30, 54, 72, 84, 90, 90, 84, 72, 54, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple algorithms problem:

```
inc = 0
x = 2

while True:
    x += inc
    inc += 2

    if x > 100:
        break
    print(x)
```

Comment: @JoshuaNixon I could've if I wanted to print `N` numbers, but in this case I wanted to print the sequence up to a max value of 100, for which I don't know how many numbers need to be printed beforehand

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question. I read it as just asking for a step of 2 each time. (:

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
[2*sum(range(i)) for i in range(2,8)]
```

Output:

```
[2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42]
```

Change `end` of range function accordingly to get further sequence.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a O(N^2) approach.  For instance, if I change the upper limit `8` to `1000`, this will do a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: my bad. should've used DP approach.